# Ruby on Rails Javascript to Disable Text Field With Checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I'm am currently using  form_for in one of my views with the following fields

```
<%= f.checkbox :free %>
<%= f.checkbox :rsvp %>

<%= f.textfield :price %>
```

Also, I'm completely lost on how to actually embed javascript within my html/erb views to get everything working together.

First of all I want to be able to only allow one of them to be used at a time. For instance, if one box is checked the other box and price are disabled. And if there is a price entered, then the two boxes are disabled.

I think I can do something like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#event_free").click(function () {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $("#event_price").prop("disabled", true);
        } else {
            $("#event_price").prop("disabled", false);
        }
    });
});
```

Of course this is only for the free checkbox. There has to be a better way of doing this.

Comment: You want only one of the checkboxes to be selected, Whats wrong with __radio options__?

Comment: I figured that with radio buttons you would end up with one of them selected. Yet in this case the text box also needs to be enabled/disabled

Comment: Your current jQuery script can be used with slight modification

Comment: Modification in what way, other than to include the obvious other conditionals for each button and textbox? My main issue is how to include the script in an embeded ruby file.

Comment: I am noob with ruby, So can't suggest you in that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To embed javascript in your .html.erb file use the following anywhere in the file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //your javascript code here
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago I was faced with similar problem. This might help you:

HTML:

```
<div data-limited-checkboxes data-limit="3">
  <input type="checkbox" checked />
  <input type="checkbox" checked />
  <input type="checkbox" checked />
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <input type="checkbox" />
</div>
```

JS:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  var restrictCheckboxes = function(container) {
    var limit = $(container).data("limit");
    var checkboxes = $(container).find("input:checkbox");
    var selectedCount = checkboxes.filter(":checked").length;

    checkboxes.filter(":not(:checked)").prop("disabled", parseInt(limit) <= selectedCount);
  };

  $("[data-limited-checkboxes] input:checkbox").bind("change", function(checkbox) {
    restrictCheckboxes($(this).parents("[data-limited-checkboxes]"));
  });

  $("[data-limited-checkboxes]").each(function() {
    restrictCheckboxes($(this));
  });
});
```